# How to update GraphQL query on button click

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm looking for a good way to update the "**orderBy: createdAt_ASC**" portion of the below graphql query when one of the two buttons below are clicked.

The default order is createAt_ASC and want the user to be able to switch between them.

```
const ALL_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
  query ALL_ITEMS_QUERY {
    items(orderBy: createdAt_ASC) {
      id
      title
      description
      image
    }
  }
`;
```

Buttons:

```
<button onClick={sortNew}>Newest</button>
<button onClick={sortOld}>Oldest</button>
```

Comment: Are you using apollo client, redux form or redux?

Comment: [GraphQL variables](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) will almost certainly be part of the answer, but without knowing how you’re making the GraphQL call it’s hard to tell you how to wire that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change your query

```
const ALL_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
  query ALL_ITEMS_QUERY($orderBy: String!) {
    items(orderBy: $orderBy) {
      id
      title
      description
      image
    }
  }
`;
```

On react component use react-apollo

```
import { compose, graphql } from 'react-apollo'
class ReactComponentName extends Component {
......
//Inside render return this buttons
<button onClick={this.changeOrder.bind(this,"sortNew")}>Newest</button>
<button onClick={this.changeOrder.bind(this,"sortOld")}>Oldest</button>

.......
// And change your export statement and using HOC
export default compose(
  graphql(ALL_ITEMS_QUERY, { name: 'allItemQuery' }),
  // import query and  bind this into props using compose
)(ReactComponentName)
```

onClick call a function

```
  async changeOrder(order) {
    const { allItemQuery } = this.props
    const result = await allItemQuery({ variables: { 'orderBy': order } })
    //Set state or store filter data
  }
```

Change your state variable or render result data.

Or

Do this cool [Query component](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries) in Apollo client